# openshift python echo websocket server

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, openshift

I am trying to create an echo server in python that runs correctly on OpenShift. Here how it looks now:

```
from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/a')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/')
def api():
    if request.environ.get('wsgi.websocket'):
        ws = request.environ['wsgi.websocket']
        print ws
        while True:
            message = ws.receive()
            ws.send(message)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ip   = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_IP']
    port = int(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_PORT'])
    print port, ip
    http_server = WSGIServer((ip,port), app, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
    http_server.serve_forever()
```

However, it doesn't seems to work. I don't get any error messages.( except on the client side.) I wonder if any of you could help with this. I have been looking for a solution for one and a half weeks now, and I am really on my nuts. I would also appreciate any working example.
Please **note** that many examples from the internet are not working on OpenShift due to port, domain restrictions. Please help me with this. **Please** anwser if you are sure about your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to connect to specific ports, as the main routing layer is still Apache based and does not support WebSockets.

So, for plain WebSockets ws:// you will use port 8000 and for secured connections wss:// port 8443. Here's an example:

```
http://app-lovingwebsockets.rhcloud.com/  <= your current HTTP URL
http://app-lovingwebsockets.rhcloud.com:8000/ <= WebSockets enables HTTP URL

https://app-lovingwebsockets.rhcloud.com/  <= your current HTTPs URL
https://app-lovingwebsockets.rhcloud.com:8443/ <= WebSockets enables HTTPs URL
```

Here's a great Python example https://github.com/Lawouach/WebSocket-for-Python